# Need advice on air compressor for home use

Tags: tools, garage, compressor

I'm in the market for a cheap air compressor. I need it for the occasional spray painting of furniture, inflating and switching of tires.

I've been looking at this air compressor:

[image: stanley air compressor]

The specs of the compressor are as follows:

- 2hp (1500 Watts)
- ~6 gallons in the tank (24 litres)
- ~7.8 CFM (222 litres per minute)
- ~116 PSI (8 bar)
- Oil lubricated

Is this device going to fulfill my needs (based on the specs)? I've read that oil can leak into the air causing problems with spray painting. Is that something which can be prevented?

Comment: You will also have problems spray painting with that due to it producing wet air.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/413/33).

Comment: You can get filters and dryers, to remove oil and water vapor.

Comment: Do you have the specs for the sprayer you plan to use? It should have a consumption rating, usually in cubic feet per minute (CFM).

Comment: I haven't decided on a sprayer. I don't own one and I figured I would buy an air compressor first. I looked over the link you provided to the other question. It seems like this compressor is under-powered in terms of CFM(?). I will go search google for the filters and dryers, thank you :-)

Comment: Finish sprayers take a lot of air, whether old hplv or new hvlp types. You might want to instead consider a turbine-driven hvlp system, or one of the latest generation of airless sprayers (which, unlike their paint-spraying  predecessors, really can efficiently  lay down a furniture-quality coating). Of you could get a small compressor for tires and air tools, and stick with brushed/padded finishes, which is what I've done so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to purchase an air compressor to use for painting it may cost more than if you purchase a dedicated airless paint sprayer. Both tools are priced about the same (for mid priced tools). But you will also need a sprayer for the compressor and a desiccator and contaminate filter which will increase the cost for painting with a compressor. Air compressors, even the smaller models, weigh a lot and are awkward to carry. Airless sprayers are straight forward: easy to clean, no extra accessories to begin painting, light weight, and do a fast and excellent job. Here is a link for the one I bought 7 years ago and still use: http://www.lowes.com/ProductDisplay?partNumber=295433-48690-LTS+17&catalogId=10051&storeId=10151&langId=-1&productId=4745131  Here is the compressor I compared it against:http://www.lowes.com/ProductDisplay?partNumber=155839-70-D55146&catalogId=10051&storeId=10151&langId=-1&productId=1036715